# drcsim-nightly/sandia-hand-nightly dependency bug

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I try to install drcsim-nightly using

```
sudo apt-get install drcsim-nightly
```

having already installed gazebo-nightly and sandia-hand-nightly,
I get the following error message:

```
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 drcsim-nightly : Depends: sandia-hand-nightly (>= 5.1.10) but 5.1.10~hg20130325rb995efea5e65-1~precise is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Looks like the system can't figure out that version
5.1.10~hg20130325rb995efea5e65-1~precise is >= 5.1.10

Any suggestions?
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2064/drcsim-nightly/sandia-hand-nightly-dependency-bug/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-03-26**:
Just tried, happens for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a bug in versioning for drcsim nightly releases.

Debian versioning policy (and Ubuntu) considers *5.1.10* greater than *5.1.10~hgxxx* so the system is complaining about now having a valid sandia-hand *>=5.1.10* version.

A [fix](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim-release/commits/81463c3f3bcb60deba42520c89f66384f5a1b641) is already in the repo and should make tomorrow nightly build to not suffer from this error.

**Workaround:**

Download manually drcsim-nightly package from [gazebosim.org](http://gazebosim.org/assets/distributions/) and install it ignoring sandia-hand dependency:

> sudo apt-get install sandia-hand-nightly # to be sure of have it installed

> sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=sandia-hand-nightly drcsim-nightly_*.deb

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-04-01**:
Has anyone gotten nightly build to work since this fix?  Both times I tried it screwed up the install, and had to spend time cleaning up to re-install release version.

**Comment by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on 2013-04-01**:
Working for me. Install gazebo-nightly, then sandia-hand-nightly (which installs osrf-common-nightly), then drcsim-nightly

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-04-01**:
For my system (precise with amd64) without any OSRF related package, an apt-get install drcsim-nightly is enough (it will pull gazebo, osrf-common, sandia-hand and drcsim). All fails can be consider bugs and reported in drcsim-release bitbucket repository.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-04-01**:
Do you need to remove the current release installs prior to installing nightly?

**Comment by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on 2013-04-01**:
Installing xxx-nightly automatically "uninstalls" xxx. I don't know if manually uninstalling xxx and then installing xxx-nightly is an approved procedure.

**Comment by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on 2013-04-01**:
By the way, you can't mix drcsim/gazebo installations using apt-get and those where you compile source. Unless you intervene, apt-get installations install to /usr/share, bin, include, lib while compiling by source installs to /usr/local/share, bin, include, lib. Unless you are very careful with your $PATH, these two installations interfere with each other. So no compiling by source if you want to use the nightly versions.